# Use a set of structs and avoid duplicate structs in a set

Tags: c++, struct, graph, set, undirected-graph

I am trying to represent a non-directional graph. I created three structs as shown below. I added operator == and operator < to the Edge struct hoping the set would use it to compare elements.

```
struct  Node;   /* Forward references to these two types */
struct Edge;     /* that the compiler can recognize them */

/* Type: Node
 * This type represents an individual node and consists of the data of the 
 *  node and the set of edges from this node */
struct Node{
    int nodeNum;
    string data;
    set<Edge*> edges;
};


/* Type: Edge
 * This type represents an individual edge and consists of pointers to the 
 * endpoints */
struct Edge{
    Node *end1;
    Node *end2;

    // This says that edge from node 1 to node 2 and edge from node 2 to node 1 are considered the same
    bool operator==(const Edge &e) const{
        return ( (this->end1->nodeNum == e.end1->nodeNum && this->end2->nodeNum == e.end2->nodeNum) ||
                 (this->end1->nodeNum == e.end2->nodeNum && this->end2->nodeNum == e.end1->nodeNum));
    }

    // This function is used by set to order elements of edges.
    bool operator<(const Edge *e) const{
        return (this->end1 < e->end1 && this->end2 < e->end2);
    }
};


// This is a struct for graph
struct Graph{
    set<Node*> Nodes;
    set<Edge*> Edges;
    map<int, Node*> nodeMap;
};
```

Question: If say, I have an edge from node 1 to 2 and an edge from 2 to 1, my struct declaration says they should be considered equivalent. Yet when I insert those two edges in a set, it inserts both of them as two separate elements (i.e. set does not understand that edge 1-2 and 2-1 are equal). What do I do so that the set took care of duplicates (i.e. only keeps one of these edges). See e.g. below:

```
 int main(){
    // Let's make 2 nodes, node 1 and node 2
    Node* n1 = new Node;
    Node* n2 = new Node;
    n1->nodeNum=1;
    n2->nodeNum=2;

    // Let's make 2 edges 1-2 and 2-1
    Edge* e1 = new Edge;
    Edge* e2 = new Edge;
    e1->end1=n1; e1->end2=n2;
    e2->end1=n2; e2->end2=n1;

    // Now let's make a graph and put the edges in its internal set
    Graph g;
    g.Edges.insert(e1);  
    g.Edges.insert(e2);  // the set takes in both e1 and e2. If I print all elements in g.Edges, it will print both 1-2 and 2-1
    // How do I tell the set to treat e1 and e2 as equal edges so it took care of duplicates?

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Are you aware that std::set doesn't use operator==?

Comment: Also, std::set<T*> will create a set of unique adresses, not unique values.

Comment: @NeilButterworth No I wasn't, now I am. So operators <> only?

Comment: @Frank yes, I want a set "of pointers to Edge structs". And I would like the "tell the set" that even if I have 2 edge structs with different addresses, it should look at the node numbers that each end of an edge points to and if they are the same regardless of direction, treat edges as equivalent.

Comment: Note: you should define ``Node::operator<(const Node &n)`` which you are trying to use in ``Edge::operator<(const Edge &e)``

Comment: @Sar `set` operates on [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set<T*>` will create a set of memory locations, not a set of T values.

If you want to compare the pointed objects, you need to provide a custom comparator:

```
struct Ptr_compare {
  template<typename T>
  constexpr bool operator()( const T* lhs, const T* rhs ) const {
    return *lhs < *rhs;
  }
};

// This is a struct for graph
struct Graph {
    set<Node*, Ptr_compare> Nodes;
    set<Edge*, Ptr_compare> Edges;
    map<int, Node*> nodeMap;
};
```

However:

Be aware that the code I wrote answers your question, but is still not correct for your use-case, it's only ok to use this for **non-owning pointers**, which is most definitely not your case.

This is not a problem with my solution per-se, but a fundamental issue in what you are trying to accomplish. Something needs to call `delete` on the dedupped objects.